# How to pass user data from register form to verify email blade template in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel authentication system and i want to send the email entered by user to `verify.blade.php` so that i can display something like `"A verification email sent to email@example.com"` in the `verify.blade.php`.

I don't know how to get the request data and pass to the blade template. I tried to pass the request but it does not work.

```
class VerificationController extends Controller
{

    public function show(){
        return view('auth.verify')->with('email',request()->email);
    }

}
```

How can i pass user data to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could¸ but you don't need to pass the user's email to your view.
Instead, you can simply call the `auth()->user()` method to access the authenticated user properties directly from your view.

For example, you can insert the following in your `verify.blade.php` :

```
<p>A verification link was sent to {{ auth()->user()->email }} just now.</p>
```

And it will display the authenticated user email address.